# NSInternalInconsistencyException in phone gap splash screen

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

I'm using PhoneGap 2.9.0 on IOS and building application for iPhone5.
I'm trying to change the splash screen, I followed the phonegap explanations
My actions:
1. In iPhone project -> Resources -> splash I added Default-568h@2x~iphone.png
2. And in the resources of phonegap www -> res -> screen -> ios.
3. Added to [config.xml](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml):

```
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="568" />

After that I have next exception (at the line I added the gap:splash):
2013-07-30 11:29:45.678 Test[1625:c07] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2013-07-30 11:29:45.681 Test[1625:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[CDVConfigParser parser:parseErrorOccurred:], /Users/Giora/Desktop/POCS/Test/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVConfigParser.m:93
2013-07-30 11:29:45.683 Test[1625:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'config.xml parse error line 55 col 46'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x16b012 0x28c9e7e 0x16ae78 0x1557f35 0x72fa2 0x15a02d8 0x58b52af 0x58cf745 0x58d725a 0x58d94e5 0x58d8f07 0x15a01ce 0x15a0160 0x15a0416 0x15a04ca 0x53d78 0x52bf0 0x52cbe 0x7b959 0x48546e 0x52d4e 0x7b9bd 0x7b47b 0x3a37b7 0x3a3da7 0x3a4fab 0x3b6315 0x3b724b 0x3a8cf8 0x36fbdf9 0x36fbad0 0xe0bf5 0xe0962 0x111bb6 0x110f44 0x110e1b 0x3a47da 0x3a665c 0x7b15c 0x7b0b9)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your entire config.xml file? Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code and remove above code in plugins tag (config.xml)

`<feature name="SplashScreen">
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
</feature>`